# 'Complete action Using' doesn't display all choices

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I used an `DownloadManager` to download a pdf file from a server in Android.

After download when I click a notice in notifications, it shows a dialog named `Complete action using`
But the dialog doesn't show all choices. For example, I have five apps that can open pdf file in my phone however it only shows 2 apps in list.

Well, when I open a downloaded file in browser(e.g. `Root Explorer`) it shows all choices.

What should I do to display all choices in `Complete action using` list?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to display all choices in Complete action using list?

You did not write `DownloadManager`. If you wish to change the behavior of `DownloadManager`, you would need to create your own ROM mod with your modified `DownloadManager`.

You did not write the other three PDF clients. Their developers can support whatever they want.

Hence, there is nothing you can really do, as this behavior has nothing to do with your app.

My guess is that `DownloadManager` is using a `content://` `Uri` for the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, and your three PDF apps do not support that scheme, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Can you please give me some advices about what is `ROM mod`?